# Why am I getting 'null' when I try to access my String Array?

Tags: java

I am simply trying to access my array(items[j]) which I filled by doing this:

```
                            for(int j = 0;j<items.length;j++){
                            for(int i = 0;i<prices.length;i++){
                                items[j] = x.next();
                                System.out.print(items[j] + ", ");

                                prices[i] = c.nextDouble();
                                System.out.printf("$%.2f \n", prices[i]);
```

The Code above works as intended, however a 'null' problem occurs when I try access the array(items[j]) outside the for loop.
**Like this:**

```
    System.out.printf("%s, ", items[5]); //accessing 6th item on the menu(Coffee)
    System.out.printf("$%.2f", prices[5]); //accessing 6th items price.(2.59)
```

**My Output:**

```
null, $2.59
```

It seems to work for the Prices array, just not for the Items array.

**My Expected Output:**

```
Coffee, $2.59
```

**Here is my full code if there is any confusion:**

```
            int size = 1000;
            String [] items =  new String[10];
            double [] prices = new double[size];
                System.out.println(" ");
                    File fileText = new File("inventory.txt");
                    Scanner x = new Scanner(fileText);
                    x.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]+"  + "[^A-Z a-z]+");

                    Scanner c = new Scanner(fileText);
                    c.useDelimiter("[^0-99.99]+");
                    try{

                        System.out.println("The items in inventory.txt are: ");

                        while(x.hasNext()&&c.hasNext()){
                            for(int j=0;j<items.length;j++){
                                for(int i = 0;i<prices.length;i++){
                                    items[j] = x.next();
                                    System.out.print(items[j] + ", ");

                                    prices[i] = c.nextDouble();
                                    System.out.printf("$%.2f \n", prices[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    x.close();
                    c.close();
                    }   
        catch(NoSuchElementException g){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

        System.out.printf("%s, ", items[5]); //accessing 6th item on the menu(Coffee)
        System.out.printf("$%.2f", prices[5]); //accessing 6th items price.(2.59)
```

**The text file my program is reading, (inventory.txt):**

```
Espresso, 2.10

Mochaccino, 5.99

Irish Coffee, 7.99

Caffe Americano, 6.40

Latte, 1.99

Coffee, 2.59

Cappuccino, 3.50

blackCoffee, 8.90

whiteCoffee, 5.54

yellowCoffee, 4.80

greenCoffee, 6.12

purpleCoffee, 3.54
```

Comment: What is the purpose of nesting your for loops like that? The data file doesn't suggest that each item has multiple prices... You can (and should) be reading a full line of data on each iteration of a single loop. Try that and then see if your problem doesn't magically go away.

Comment: Also, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: Thank you for time, that seemed to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I avoided using the delimiters because they are not necessary and I removed a useless *for-loop* which was also contested in a comment by *[MarsAtomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305826/marsatomic)*...

> What is the purpose of nesting your for loops like that? The data file doesn't suggest that each item has multiple prices... You can (and should) be reading a full line of data on each iteration of a single loop. Try that and then see if your problem doesn't magically go away.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int size = 1000, commaIndex = 0;
    String[] items = new String[10];
    double[] prices = new double[size];

    File fileText = new File("inventory.txt");
    Scanner c = new Scanner(fileText);
    try {
        System.out.println("The items in inventory.txt are: ");

        while (c.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                String line = c.nextLine();
                // Empty line is scanned so i need to decrease j
                // in order to have the right indexes for items and prices
                if (line.isEmpty())
                    j--;
                commaIndex = line.indexOf(",");
                items[j] = line.substring(0, commaIndex);
                prices[j] = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(commaIndex + 2));  
            }
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException g) {
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    System.out.printf("%s, ", items[5]); //accessing 6th item on the menu(Coffee)
    System.out.printf("$%.2f", prices[5]); //accessing 6th items price.(2.59)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been able to finish the rest of my assignments because of this!